# Cannot use Windows Authentication with .eap file (Enterprise Architect version 13)

Tags: active-directory, enterprise-architect

I've imported some users from Active Directory into Enterprise Architect (Enable windows Authentication is enabled) and placed the .eap file in a shared folder.

In principal EA should automatically detect the Windows users and they should have access to the model (without being asked to enter the password). It seem not to be the case for .eap file as it asks for Login and password.

I have tested it with model in the Oracle server and it seem to be working fine for my account but with .eap file, it fails.

Did anyone else have the same issue? Does anyone know a solution to it?
I'm using EA version 13.5.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason EA disables windows authentication access the moment a .eap file is moved to another location.

You have to re-enable it using the option **Configure | Security | Users**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok it is solved. I have to toggle the checkbox 'Enable windows authentication' for the users, after putting the file in the shared folder. :)